# AWS S3 Image is not opening when uploaded

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

Implemented a Rest service to upload file/image using **aws-java-sdk version 1.11** in spring boot.

This is my endpoint - `POST uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files`.
I'm able to upload from my local server and image url opens/loads in the browser.

Now I deployed this code to sandbox server running in AWS ECS.
The image upload works fine in ECS as well but when I try to open the link it fails to load. **Error : Cannot be displayed because it contains errors**

Code is same and bucket has public access. Anybody faced similar issue or any input is much appreciated?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get get link

Comment: In your local, did you try to use the same policies that is attached the IAM role used in ECS.

Comment: @ArunK : This is how I'm getting the URL amazonS3Client.getUrl(bucketName, uniqueFileName)

Comment: What does it give you, a presigned url? Is it possible the url is expired when you checked ?

Comment: Its not presigned url as far as I know. I'm not sure if its expired or not as the error just says :  Cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: Can you go into the AWS Console and manually access the file? Can you manually download the file you've uploaded, does it open locally?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver and ArunK : Whatever you suspected is true I guess. When I tried to open locally its giving error with msg containing Token, Signature etc. How to fix it?

Comment: i think its a pre-signed url

Comment: nop, `s3.getSignedUrl ` to get signed url, i dont see any `getUrl`

Comment: nop, `s3.getSignedUrl ` to get signed url, i dont see any `getUrl`

Comment: ok ignore me, can you inspect properties of one of the files that you tried to download in S3, check if it's really public.

Comment: Bucket is already public added policy for GetObject. Remember if upload from local everything works fine.